# Report Designer Validation Failed on Pentaho 5.2 BA Server

Tags: pentaho

I am using a Report Designer version 5.2 and I am trying to deploy a report into the BA server (5.2) and I am getting this 'Report validation failed.' what should be happening?

can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally this issue occurs when upload a prpt from windows machine to PUC when Pentaho server is hosted in a Linux machine. Because ktr path is set in windows format (example: D:\Reports\test.ktr) in prpt.
You need to manually copy the ktr to linux server and correct the path in linux format.
Hope this helps.